# how to trigger original event with JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

So sorry for my bad English words.

Hello, I have some problem when firing custom event in JQuery.
My problem is :

- I try to develop Google chrome extension using `content_scripts` API.
- The site that i target is publishing the comments if i press enter key on textArea.
- I need to develop a button which fire the same event if i click on it.

I tried to simulate the same thing using http://jsfiddle.net/ editor like this:

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
// this what the site do when press enter key on textarea , the submit form with ajax to publish a comment.
          $("textarea").bind("keydown",function(e){
            if(e.which == 13){
              alert("enter pressed");
            }
          });
    // this what i need to do, firing the same event when i click on my button which i added by my extension.
          $("button").click(function(){
            var e = $.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 13;
            $("textarea").trigger(e);
          });
        });
```

the code above is run without any problem but when apply this simulation in target website no action happening . 
i imagine if the site using keydown, keyup, or keypress events to publish comment, so i tried using all event types, but all my tries failed.
What i can do to fire the same of original event such as actual pressing enter key to submit comment ?

Comment: I would create a method which should be called within the KeyDown event handler and button's Click.  It is easy and looks much more better than triggering an event manually....

Comment: I think his problem is that he doesn't implement the original event handler method, it's whatever the web page does. He just wants to provide a new way of triggering it.

Comment: @Barmar, his code contains $("textarea").trigger();  so, the problem is in triggering the event and the corresponding event handler.  Thus my solution should meet ideally...

Comment: That's just for his SSCE. Read his description of the real application: it's a Chrome extension that's intended to work with another site. He wants to trigger the action defined by that other site.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a new function to submit your comment and call it when :

- User press ENTER in the textarea
- User click on the button

  ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       function submitComment()
       {
           //Do what you want to submit the textarea text
           var comment = $("textarea").html();
       }

       $("textarea").bind("keydown",function(e){
          if(e.which == 13){
             submitComment();
          }
       });

       $("button").click(function(){
          submitComment();
       });
   });
  ```

Comment: No i can't call JavaScript function from the site in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

why not try separating your logic?  This is not tested code so you might have to play with it, but this general style will work and accomplish what it seems you are trying to do.

```
function myFunction()
{

    alert("enter pressed");
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
// this what the site do when press enter key on textarea , the submit form with ajax to publish a comment.
          $("textarea").bind("keydown",function(e){
             if(eventArg.which == 13){
                    myFunction();

              }
          });


    // this what i need to do, firing the same event when i click on my button which i added by my extension.
 $("button").click(function(){
         myFunction();
   });
 });
```

Comment: No i can't call JavaScript function from the site in my extension.